# Need jQuery opposite to document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a function that will trigger some JavaScript code before the page loads. It's the opposite of document.ready

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Laurent

Comment: code outside document.ready....

Comment: You need what now? Why would you need to do something explicitly *before* the page loads, and what exactly would that be, I'm really curious?

Comment: Just run the code directly.

Comment: @adeneo i'm also curious... cant see any reason to do that

Comment: @GertB. - I get why you don't want to wait for DOM ready or window onload, but **before** the page loads sounds a lot like someone is doing something they probably shouldn't be doing ?

Comment: It sounds like you are wanting to execute data before ready, which is usually in the server language.

Granted, the issue at hand is that the html might not be ready and would cause errors on whatever you are doing.  I would highy reccomend you rethink your reasoning behind your notion.

Comment: An alert window (in the `head`) prevents the page load. Isn't there a way to fake that without the alert window?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
              //code here will run when encountered...
              //to ensure jQuery not loaded you can do this:
              if ( typeof jQuery  == undefined ){
                  //jQuery be like not there.
              }
       </script>

        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `jQuery == undefined` will produce a reference error use `window.jQuery` or `typeof jQuery === "undefined"`

Comment: it just means there is no object named jQuery, jQuery is jQuery.  It becomes $ upon load and after a copy of whatever $ was before.

Comment: Yes but if jQuery is not loaded yet then you will get a reference error exception when you try to use the global `jQuery`

Comment: @megawac, the way I use it works perfectly fine on IE and Chrome but I have seen the way you describe as well.

Comment: And yet, doing it like this wouldn't give you access to any DOM elements ?

Comment: @adeneo, you would access to all available DOM objects.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/OnImiHUV/1 it should throw in any browser (copy paste of your code)

Answer (score 0):

You can just run the code directly before referencing any other script (if you're not dealing with async tasks it should be ok).

You can have a IOC or boot script to load the libs, it should be easy. In frameworks like AngularJS you've this natively, but check [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for example.

How about using a [ServiceWorker](https://github.com/slightlyoff/ServiceWorker/)? Again, it depends of what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is built into jQuery but you can write a plugin to do it. The code just has to be placed at the top of the page

```
(function($){
    $.fn.notReady = function(func){
         return func();
    }
})(jQuery);

$(document).notReady(function(){
     alert("Hello World!");
});
```

You could also use the [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/) framework instead of jQuery. It is cross platform and has this feature built in.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery **[$.holdReady()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.holdready/)** method, which **holds** or **releases** the execution of jQuery's ready event.

**Example:**

```
    $.holdReady(true);
    // your javascript code before the ready event
    $.holdReady(false);
```

> From jQuery documentation

The **$.holdReady()** method allows the caller to delay jQuery's ready event. This advanced feature would typically be used by dynamic script loaders that want to load additional JavaScript such as jQuery plugins before allowing the ready event to occur, even though the DOM may be ready. This method must be called early in the document, such as in the `<head>` immediately after the jQuery script tag. Calling this method after the ready event has already fired will have no effect.

To delay the ready event, first call *$.holdReady( true )*. When the ready event should be released to execute, call *$.holdReady( false )*. Note that multiple holds can be put on the ready event, one for each *$.holdReady( true )* call. The ready event will not actually fire until all holds have been released with a corresponding number of *$.holdReady( false )* calls and the normal document ready conditions are met. (See [ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for more information.)